# Need help to identify this component from an LED driver module

Tags: identification, component-selection

I got an LED driver module(LDM) from a truck that drives the headlight of the truck.

The PCB has a strange component which I have never seen before. I have added a picture of that component. The component is used in the input side so I think it may be a TVS diode or MOV.

1. It is a 2 terminal device.
2. One terminal is connected to the input line and another terminal to the ground.
3. The LDM has 24 volts DC and 960mA current input supply, 23 watts rated power on LDM

[image]

[image]

note:- position of the component is highlighted

Comment: 24 V sounds load dump capable to me so GDT, MOV är TVR would be my guess. Can you follow the traces and find approximately where it sits in the schematic?

Comment: @winny it is hard to find the trace because it is a multi-layer board. but I'm sure that it is at input side of DC-DC.

Comment: Multimeter is your friend!

Comment: @winny uploaded the schematic.

Comment: Good! My previous suggestion stands.